# Use D3 mouse event coordinates in Vue.js components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I just started learning D3 and I am trying to integrate a scatter plot chart in a Vue.js component. Things went ok until I wanted to integrate tooltips on mouseover.

The original code for the mouseover function was something like this:

```
var mousemove = function(d) {
    tooltip
        .html("Sold quantity: " + d.quantity + "<br> Object price: " + d.price)
        .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+90) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
};
```

Then, it was attached to an on event method.

Now, if I try to take the code and use it in Vue.js, I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: node.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

And I understand why this is. Basically, the `this` instance is now the whole Vue.js component instance. Before, `this` was simply referring to the DOM element the mouse was hovered over.

There are some solutions online, but none could solve this particular case, where somebody just wants to access/ set the correct `this` context for d3 to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, you cannot use `this` inside a D3 listener — vue.js being just one of these reasons — use the third and second arguments combined:

```
var mousemove = function(d,i,n) {
    tooltip
        .html("Sold quantity: " + d.quantity + "<br> Object price: " + d.price)
        .style("left", (d3.mouse(n[i])[0]+90) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.mouse(n[i])[1]) + "px")
};
```

In short, change `this` for `a[b]`, where `a` is the third argument and `b` is the second (in most of D3 codes, they are named `n` for nodes and `i` for index).